Continuity almost everywhere of a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$
Let $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and take $\overline{u}$ a representant of $u$. Suppose $\overline{u}(x_0) < 0$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Can we say that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\overline{u}(x) < 0$ for $x \in B_\delta(x_0)$ almost everywhere? If this is not true, what about if we take $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

You might also be interested in Sobolev embeddings, because for the case $N=1$, your claim actually holds true for $u\in H^1(\mathbb R)$. This is because $H^1(\mathbb R)$ embeds into $C^{0,1/2}(\mathbb R)$ (which is the space of $1/2$-Hölder continuous functions on $\mathbb R$).

Consider, $u=\chi_{B_1(x_0)-\{x_0\}}-5\chi_{\{x_0\}}$. Then $u(x_0)<0$ but $u(x)>0$ a.e. on $B_{1}(x_0)$, and $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$The problem lies on the fact that you can take any function and tweak it on a point to get an a.e. equal function. Now there is a density theorem of continuous functions in $L^2$ (or $L^p$ in general) but it also requires compact support.
Also note that this works for any ball (take $u=\chi_{B_{\delta}(x_0)-\{x_0\}}-5\chi_{\{x_0\}}$ ) and it also works for weakly differentiable functions.
